Android KeyboardAvoidingView button is partially above keyboard on first open
I'm building a React Native screen where I want a "Continue" button to be positioned just above the keyboard when the input field is focused. I've implemented this using KeyboardAvoidingView with the following code:
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPress={() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }}
>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.white, paddingHorizontal: 16 }}
    behavior={Platform.select({
      ios: 'padding',
      android: 'height',
    })}
    enabled
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ ios: 100, android: 80 })}
  >
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      {content}
     <Button
          title='Continue'
          onPress={onPress}
          style={{marginTop: 16, marginHorizontal: 16, marginBottom: 32}
          disabled={!validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
        />
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>


On iOS, everything works perfectly.
On Android, the first time the keyboard opens, the "Continue" button is partially above the keyboard, not fully. On next openings, the button positions correctly, but a blank space is added at the bottom of the screen.
How can the "Continue" button be always fully above the keyboard the first time it opens on Android and without adding unwanted blank space at the bottom of the screen?
